# Excel VBA target cell on change then ignore

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that detects when a cell is changed, and adds this number to cell above it.

However I then need to clear the original cell, which always triggers the macro again as that cell is being changed again, and I end up an endless loop. Is there a way to "ignore" any other cell changes whilst the macro runs?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("B3:O3")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    If Range(Target.Address).Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Range(Target.Address).Offset(-1).Value = Range(Target.Address).Offset(-1).Value + Range(Target.Address).Value
        Range(Target.Address).Clear
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Application.EnableEvents` to keep the loop from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or simply add `Application.EnableEvents` as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("B3:O3")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    If Range(Target.Address).Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range(Target.Address).Offset(-1).Value = Range(Target.Address).Offset(-1).Value + Range(Target.Address).Value
        Range(Target.Address).Clear
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional condition:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("A3:O3")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing And Range(Target.Address).Value <> "" Then
    If Range(Target.Address).Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Range(Target.Address).Offset(-1).Value = Range(Target.Address).Offset(-1).Value + Range(Target.Address).Value
        Range(Target.Address).Clear
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Adding the additional condition still triggers the change event 3 times. An interesting approach but not efficient.